# Why no "System Restart Required" message after Amazon Linux kernel update?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I ran `sudo yum update` on an Amazon Linux instance and it updated the kernel. On other distos I've seen, this causes a message to appear when you login saying `System Restart Required`.  Why don't I see it here?

```
Last login: Mon Jun  2 17:06:11 2014 from ...

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.03-release-notes/

[myuser@dev ~]$ uname -a
Linux dev.myhost.com.au 3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 24 16:31:21 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[myuser@dev ~]$ cd /boot

[myuser@dev boot]$ ls -l 
total 45208
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    80189 May  6 04:31 config-3.10.38-49.136.amzn1.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    80189 May 14 07:38 config-3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    70178 Feb 25 03:36 config-3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jun  2 17:07 grub
-rw------- 1 root root 10203096 May 12 03:58 initramfs-3.10.38-49.136.amzn1.x86_64.img
-rw------- 1 root root 10203665 Jun  2 17:07 initramfs-3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64.img
-rw------- 1 root root  8777362 Mar  4 23:18 initramfs-3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   128784 May  6 04:31 symvers-3.10.38-49.136.amzn1.x86_64.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   128805 May 14 07:38 symvers-3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64.gz
-rw------- 1 root root  2201080 May  6 04:31 System.map-3.10.38-49.136.amzn1.x86_64
-rw------- 1 root root  2201155 May 14 07:38 System.map-3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64
-rw------- 1 root root  1727495 Feb 25 03:36 System.map-3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3657552 May  6 04:31 vmlinuz-3.10.38-49.136.amzn1.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3659152 May 14 07:38 vmlinuz-3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3145488 Feb 25 03:36 vmlinuz-3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64

[myuser@dev boot]$ cat grub/grub.conf 
# created by imagebuilder
default=0
timeout=1
hiddenmenu

title Amazon Linux 2014.03 (3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64)
root (hd0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64 root=LABEL=/ console=hvc0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
initrd /boot/initramfs-3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64.img

title Amazon Linux 2014.03 (3.10.38-49.136.amzn1.x86_64)
root (hd0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.38-49.136.amzn1.x86_64 root=LABEL=/ console=hvc0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
initrd /boot/initramfs-3.10.38-49.136.amzn1.x86_64.img

title Amazon Linux 2013.09 (3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64)
root (hd0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64 root=LABEL=/ console=hvc0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
initrd /boot/initramfs-3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64.img
```

Reboot system and confirm the new kernel is running...

```
Last login: Thu Jun  5 10:55:30 2014 from ...

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.03-release-notes/
[myuser@dev ~]$ uname -a
Linux dev.myhost.com.au 3.10.40-50.136.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 13 21:35:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's mainly an Ubuntu thing (and I suppose Debian).  It's part of the update-motd system, where there's a bunch of scripts in /etc/update-motd.d that occasionally rewrite the Message Of The Day that gets displayed when you first log in.  [Here's the Ubuntu wiki page on this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd)

Amazon Linux is derived from Red Hat Enterprise Linux (i.e., you are using "yum" instead of "apt"), and apparently doesn't have a dynamic message of the day system.